# apache reverse tor proxy to btcpay on umbrel does not show secure connection

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse tor proxy to btcpayserver on an umbrel. When I login, it shows an SSL connection (lock is present in the browser bar) but btcpay shows You cannot login over an insecure connection. Please use HTTPS or Tor.
I have the identical setup to btcpay via apache to a start9 embassy that works fine.

This is the apache conf file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9083/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9083/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
```

Any suggestions on modifying this?

This exact setup works against a competitive personal server, the start9 embassy.
It seems the Umbrel environment may be lacking or blocking something.